# Installing .deb package using gdebi

Tags: 18.10, gdebi

I'm having some problems installing .deb packages on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.10
I'm completely new to Linux so please explain.

First I downloaded some .deb packages via Firefox, then I just double clicked one and the Ubuntu Software Center started.
I pressed 'Install', it then asked me for my password which I entered.
At first it would just go back to the Install button, but now after trying a lot of Terminal commands it just shows a progress bar which stays at 0%.

Like I said I tried a lot of commands that I found after some Googling. I also tried installing Gdebi but that resulted in following Error which I couldn't resolve with Googling:

```
dirk@Ubuntu-L:~$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
[sudo] password for dirk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 discord : Depends: libatomic1 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libc++1
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.7+nmu2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gnome-icon-theme but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: libgtk2-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Basically I need help installing .deb packages. The "normal" Ubuntu doesn't seem to work which I found is a common problem with the solution to use Gdebi.
But Gdebi also doesn't seem to work for me.
Currently I'm quite close to just re-installing my whole Ubuntu system and hoping it works then. Or just going back to Windows which I luckily still have in a multi-boot.

Comment: Is it really the 8.10 version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6 according to the version numbers of gdebi I guess its 18.10.

Comment: @Pilot6 did I say 8.10? I of course meant 18.10.  
https://prnt.sc/mqbzmj

Comment: I don't think you need `gdebi` these days, plain `apt` supports installing from a file. The only trick is that to make it recognize arguments as local files you need to prefix the path with either `./` or `/`. So, like, instead of `sudo apt install my_file.deb` you have to write `sudo apt install ./my_file.deb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` in a terminal.

Then you can install gdebi.

Comment: I'm extremely sure I already tried this command a couple times but for some reason it worked this time. Thank you very much this fixed my problem.